# Where to find data regarding home types and addresses/zips in the US?

Tags: usa, postal-code, real-estate

I am looking for the following, not everything is necessary, but I would like to somehow extract latitude and longitude for later mapping, and knowing where condos are located is a must:

**Necessary:**

1. Home Type (Condo, Town Home, Single Family, etc.)
2. Zip (or preferably lattitude and longitude)

**Nice to Have**

3. Home Estimate and/or last sale price and/or last tax assessment evaluation
4. Home Square footage
5. Last time the home sold
6. By-Law Type (loss assessment, liability only, etc. would only apply to condos)

MLS data only has current listings, and broken up by city, which is a pain to put together, and does not give me all the information I need anyway

Answer (score 1):

Real state data is easy to get because you can gather it for free from local municipality or city hall, local MLS offices/data or local tax assessor's offices throughout the U.S (if the required data is needed in the US, I suppose other countries work more or less the same). The drawback is that they often require heavy processing and even digitalizing data.

You will probably be able to find intermediaries or data providers like Quandl. They have the [Zillow's API for housing data publicly available](https://blog.quandl.com/api-for-housing-data).